# Searching JSon string using java

Tags: java, json

I am new To JSon and i want to search the following json string and get the required output.
String:

```
{"status":"Success","code":"200","message":"Retrieved Successfully","reason":null,"
 "projects":
   [
       {
           "projectName": "example",
           "users":
           [
               {
                   "userName": "xyz",
                   "executions":
                   [
                       {
                           "status": "check",
                           "runs":
                           [
                               {
                                   "Id": "------",
                                   "Key": "---"
                               }
                           ],
                           "RCount": 1
                       }
                   ],
                   "RCount": 1
               }
           ],
           "RCount": 1
       },
```

Like that i have many projects and now , if i give projectname and username as input i wantt to get its status as output.
Is it possible?If yes how?

Comment: You have to use a Json Parser. You can find more details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java

Answer (score 2):

You may use `JSONObject` for this.

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(string);

JSONArray[] projectsArray = json.getJSONArray("projects");

for(int i = 0; i < projectsArray.length; ++i)
{
  String projectName = projectsArray[i].getString("projectName");
  ...
}
```

Use the same method to get the users.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [gson](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson) library. Using gson convert your json string to Map and then you can iterate through map to get required item

```
Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>(){}.getType();
Map<String, Object> myMap = gson.fromJson(jsonString, type);
```

Comment: Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Google gson to map your json data structure to a Java POJOs. 
Example :
You can have **Projects** class containing list/array of **Users**.
**Users** class containing list/array of **Executions** and so on.

Gson library can easily map the json to these classes as objects and you can access your data in a more elegant manner.

Here are a few references :

- http://howtodoinjava.com/2014/06/17/google-gson-tutorial-convert-java-object-to-from-json/
- http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/